# Error using ArrayList in Java

Tags: java

I was solving a problem before including it in my code and using List to get strings then work around with them. I got the error: "type List does not take parameters List  words = new ArrayList();" after compilation. I searched but the syntax i use is correct, please whats wrong with the code?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class List{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i=0; i < 3; i++)
            words.add(input.nextLine());
        System.out.println(words);
    }

}
```

Comment: Never ever use pre-defined class names as your own class name.

Comment: OK thank you! i realise that now :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is one of the reasons you should use unique names for your own classes. You are really meaning to use `java.util.List`, but since you called your class `List` as well, the real problem is masked. Rename your class and add the import for `java.util.List` to fix the issue:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyClass{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i=0; i < 3; i++)
            words.add(input.nextLine());
        System.out.println(words);
    }
}
```

Comment: OP, make sure to close input too. (NEVERMIND)

Comment: @jsn.. that is really not needed.

Comment: @RohitJain, never mind, you are right. You shouldn't close System.in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class List{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        java.util.List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i=0; i < 3; i++)
            words.add(input.nextLine());
        System.out.println(words);
    }

}
```

Your class is called List. So by default, it is assumed that the List you declared refers to your class.

It would be better to avoid names like List for your classes.